# MySql connector python не работает

Tags: python, mysql

1. Установил библиотеку (Питон ее видит)
2. Установил MySQLWorkbench (Mac OS 12.1)
3. Открыл стандартное соединение Localhost c л:п root:root
4. Записал создание таблицы в .py файл, но выдает ошибку.

Код и ошибка представлены внизу:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE mydatabase")

Error:
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `localhost` поставить `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: Не  работает( совсем такая же ошибка

Comment: Уберите `host=`, либо добавьте `port=3306`. Если в обоих случаях ошибка сохранится - проверьте, может ли подключиться CLI, если да - подключается ли он по IP или через сокет, если нет - смотрите локальный файрвол.

Comment: MySQL Workbench это средство обращения к базе данных. Вы саму базу данных MySQL установили и запустили ?